# stop voice over from saying the automatic hint for UIAccessibilityTrait adjustable (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, voiceover, uiaccessibility

When having an element on screen that has the UIAccessibilityTrait `.adjustable`, Voice Over reads out the automatic hint provided by iOS, saying "swipe up or down with one finger to adjust the value".

How do I stop iOS from saying that hint? I want voice over to only read my own accessibility hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I stop iOS from saying that hint?

When you use an accessibility element whose trait is `.adjustable`, the system will automatically read out its hint and **it's not possible to remove only this one and let yours spoken** as you wish.

However, the user can specify to stop listening to ALL hints in his settings *(iOS 12: Settings - General - Accessibility - VoiceOver - Verbosity - Speak Hints)*:
[image]

When you deal with the system hint, it's all or nothing unfortunately.