# iOS accessibility: what are the pros/cons for hardcoding "double tap to activate" as hint?

Tags: ios, accessibility

iOS has built-in support for accessibility, for `UIButton`s it reads the title of the button followed by a hint "double tap to activate" (by default). Sometimes we are required to make a non-`UIButton` control behaving similar to `UIButton` in terms of accessibility, so we would set its accessibility trait to button and hardcode "double tap to activate" for `accessibilityHint`.

I don't like altering system behaviours, and I've seen accessibility users who prefer single tap instead of double tap (there's an option they can set), although I haven't checked if the opt for single tap instead of double tap, does the system hint become "single tap to activiate".

What is the common practice regarding accessibility support for a non-`UIButton` control that is tappable? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've seen accessibility users who prefer single tap instead of double tap (there's an option they can set)

I'm really curious to know how it's possible using VoiceOver because a single tap with one finger deals with the accessibility focus. In the [UIButton documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton), Apple states:

> VoiceOver speaks the value of the title [...] when a user taps the button once.

Would you mind detailing the way to activate this option you mentioned because I'm really astonished, please?

> What is the common practice regarding accessibility support for a non-UIButton control that is tappable?

**Using a hint is a very good practice** to provide useful information to the user but this information mustn't be crucial for using because the [accessibility hint may be deactivated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56662009/3825084) in the device settings.
Admittedly speaking, this kind of element must be read out in such a way that its goal and its using are clear enough for any user: that's what traits are made for.

Many traits are well known and give rise to different actions like [`adjustable values`](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#continuous-adjustable-values), [customed actions](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#custom-actions) and the [rotor items](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#custom-rotor) using.
Besides, it's also possible to use the [`accessibilityActivate()`](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-17215.html#DefaultActivation) method so as to define the purpose of a double-tap with one finger of an accessible element.

The way you want to vocally expose the possible actions on a tappable control depends on the content of your application.

Finally, keep in mind that **hardcoding a hint** must be understood as **a plus information** but definitely **not as an essential one** because it can be deactivated by the user: a conception oriented a11y is very important when building an app.

Comment: so you are effectively suggesting that instead of hardcoding "double tap to activate" , the hint should be more contextual and talk about what the control would do ?

but technically, is there a way to enable the same message for custom controls that iOS uses for built in controls ?

Comment: @gaurav5430 Would you have an iOS built-in control example I could associate with my answer to be as accurate as possible? 

Comment: I am not really sure, i am new to ios development (through react native), but when i use voiceover most of the apps seem to announce "double tap to activate" , so i figured this must be a system default somehow.

Comment: If you're speaking of the apps icons, it's up to the iOS system and you can do nothing about it but when it deals with the elements inside your app, you don't need to specify anything if it's well designed and perfectly characterized with the appropriate trait.  Personally, I never use important hints because I do believe that the trait and the label all together are enough to make my users understand what it's all about.  Hints may be interesting by providing some bonus information but mustn't be crucial to understand the goal of the element. 